# How to relate two different django models into on many to many field form another one?

Tags: django

I'm trying to find a solution to the following problem with django models:
The app would add products to a shopping cart. The problem is that those products come from different models, and no matter where they come from, I'd like to use one ManyToManyField to incorporate them.

Suppouse I've two different kind of products from two different models:

```
Class ListOfProducts1(models.Model):
name= CharField()
price= IntegerField()

Class ListOfProducts2(models.Model):
name=CharField()
price=IntegerField()
```

The following model would be used for get the quantity and the product added(and then related to one particular order).
Here is the problem. Look to the field itemsadded, where I want to relate this field to ListOfProducts 1 and 2. I'd put both of them into the same field, but I've already know this is not possible. Just for better understanding of the problem here you have:

```
Class ProductsOrdered(models.Model):
itemsadded= OneToOneField(ListOfProducts1 and ListOfProducts2,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
Quantity = IntegerField()
```

Then the Order's model:

```
Class Orders(models.Model):
cart= ManyToManyField(ProductsOrdered)
```

Comment: You should think about why you need separate models for ListOfProducts in the first place.

Comment: And you certainly don't want a OneToOneField in ProductsOrdered, that means only one person can ever order each product. Also, why "ListOf"? Surely the models represent a Product.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I use two different models for those products because they have differents properties that cant be merged into one model

Comment: @DanielRoseman the main problem is that I want to chose one of those products from one list, no matter if they come from two different models.
It's like, merge both products into one list

Comment: You can either create a base model for both lists and inherit from that (Django Polymorphic may be handy there) or use generic relationships.

Answer (score 0):

The OneToOne fields can refer to only one table.

But you can use either GenericForeignKey or alternatives (which is better).

Look at this article: [Avoid Django’s GenericForeignKey](https://lukeplant.me.uk/blog/posts/avoid-django-genericforeignkey/). It describes alternatives, such as:

- nullable fields on source table
- intermediate table with nullable fields
- intermediate table with OneToOneFields on destination models
- multi-table inheritance
- multiple linked models